# how to replace a text in a string with other text in scala

Tags: string, scala, replace, scala-2.11

i have a following string

```
var str="ArtShare$u002ETotalArtShares"
```

i want to replace this `"$u002E"` with `"."` so that my string will become 
"ArtShare.TotalArtShares" to achieve this i used replace function

```
var str="ArtShare$u002ETotalArtShares"
var replace=str.replace(".","$u002E")
println("replaced string is "+replace)
```

but its not working following is printed on console

```
replaced string is ArtShare$u002ETotalArtShares
```

please guide me where i am doing wrong Thanks

**UPDATE** after the answer of user nyavro
i tried this

```
var str="ArtShare$u002ETotalArtShares"
var replace=str.replace("$u002E", ".")
println("replaced string is "+replace)
```

but output remains same
but the for testing i have tried this

```
 var str1="ArtShare$u002ETotalArtShares"
 var replace1=str1.replace("Total", ".")
 println("replaced string is "+replace1)
```

the following is printed

```
replaced string is ArtShare$u002E.ArtShares
```

It means code is working when i replaces Total with "." but its not working when i am giving this part of string `$u002E` please help me i did not understand why is that happening

**Update 2**
I tried doing this

```
 var str2="ArtShare$u002ETotalArtShares"
 var replace2=str2.replace("u002E", ".")
 println("replaced string is "+replace2)
```

the following is printed

```
replaced string is ArtShare$.TotalArtShares
```

after that i guess that $sign is causing the problem its not replacing please help me how can i replace that too

Comment: It works fine for me, but you might want try `str.replaceAll("\\$u002E", ".")` and see if that works for you.

Comment: str.replaceAll("\\$u002E", ".")  works for me thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JasonLenderman was close:

```
var replace = str.replaceAll("\\$U002E", ".")
```

But he mentioned that he wasn't having a problem. I initially saw the same thing, but it appears there's a difference between $u002E and $U002E where the string gets special consideration if the "U" is capitalized. If you capitalize the "U" then the following doesn't work:

```
var replace = str.replace("\\$U002E", ".")
```

Comment: thank you str.replaceAll("\\$u002E", ".")  works for me

Answer (score 5):

Switch arguments of str.replace:

```
 var replace=str.replace("$u002E", ".")
```

Comment: It definitely should. Please check your source carefully

Comment: I tried @nyavro's solution in the REPL and it worked as expected, might want to double check your source.

REPL: 
Replaying: var str="ArtShare$u002ETotalArtShares"
str: String = ArtShare$u002ETotalArtShares

Replaying:      var replace=str.replace("$u002E", ".")
replace: String = ArtShare.TotalArtShares

Replaying:     println("replaced string is "+replace)
replaced string is ArtShare.TotalArtShares

Comment: @alexanderkahoun see my answer: if you capitalize the "U" you'll be able to replicate the problem described by the op. I think the op was working with a capitalized value but didn't write the post using the capital letter.